# $\oint_C{f\nabla f}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=0$ proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I recently came across this statement which I was told was true. $$\oint_C{f\nabla f}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=0$$ Can anyone provide a proof of why this is the case? Is there any way to show that $$f\nabla f=\nabla g$$ for some function $g$?

Comment: With *no* restriction on $f$?!?

Comment: Of course you can check that $f \nabla f = \frac{1}{2} \nabla (f^{2})$.

Comment: No restriction besides $f$ being a scalar function $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @sos440 How would I go about doing that?

Comment: $$\nabla(f^2) = \frac \partial {\partial x} (f^2) \hat\imath + \frac \partial {\partial y} (f^2) \hat\jmath + \frac \partial {\partial z} (f^2) \hat k$$ Apply the chain rule?

Comment: Won't $\nabla (f^2)=2f$? I'm not very good at multivariate calculus

Comment: So make it regular calculus. Suppose we have a function g(x). What is $\frac d {dx}(g(x)^2)$?

Comment: AH I see, god sake it's so blatant. I was thinking that the derivative of $f$ was $1$ which it's clearly not. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on sos440, applying Stokes gives us:
$$\oint f \nabla f \cdot d\mathbf r = \frac 1 2 \oint \nabla (f^2) \cdot d\mathbf r = \frac 1 2 \iint \nabla \times \nabla(f^2) \cdot d\mathbf S$$
One of the non-trivial rules for $\nabla$ is that for any $g$:
$$\nabla \times \nabla g = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule for the curl of a vector field multiplied by a scalar field,

$$\nabla\times(f\nabla f)=\nabla f \times \nabla f + f\nabla\times(\nabla f)=0.$$

(Cross product of a vector with itself is identically zero, and so is the curl of a gradient field.)

Applying Stokes's theorem,

$$\oint_C{f\nabla f}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_Sd\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\times(f\nabla f)=\int_Sd\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{0}=0.$$